# What are other methods to find curvature of a polynomial apart from np.polyfit()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to find the curvature of a polynomial. X and Y are python lists of X and Y coordinates respectively. I use `scipy.interpolate` because I am able to see better curves in my image. But once I find the coefficients of a 2D polynomial and re-plot them back into the image, the replotted curve looks way too off.

- How do I find accurate coefficients of a polynomial curve

  ```
  interpolate = interpolate.interp1d(X, Y)
  z = np.polyfit(X, interpolate(X),2)  #coefficients
  poly_y = [z[0]*x*x + z[1]*x + z[2] for x in X] #Recompute Y coordinates
  plt.plot(X, poly_y)
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Thanks for the code snippet, but a more [fleshed out example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: You could use Savitzky-Golay and get the 2nd derivative from that easily.

Comment: What do you mean by "way too off"?

Comment: If you provided data along with your output, it would be much easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.polyval` instead of list comprehension to calculate the polynomial values at the given coordinates. It's usually faster, and less error-prone than typing out the terms by hand. The result will be `ndarray` instead of Python list.

```
poly_y = np.polyval(z, X)
```

If the curve looks way too off, it could be that the given degree (2) is insufficient to accurately replicate your spline-interpolated points. You should as also plot the spline interpolation `interpolate(X)` to see if something didn't go wrong in `interp1d`.